# Combining dbplyr and case_when in SQL Server

Tags: r, sql-server, dbplyr

I am using dbplyr to write and run queries in SQL Server, and want to apply a conditioned mutate. This can be done using `ifelse` or using `case_when`. The query works when using `ifelse` but throws and exception when using `case_when`.

The issue appears to be the SQL syntax that the two commands get translated into. The `case_when` syntax does not appear to be valid SQL. Can you tell me why and how to fix it? Or is this a bug?

```
# libraries
library(DBI)
library(dplyr)
library(dbplyr)

# establish connection to database table
connection_string = "database.specific.string"
# mine looks something like "DRIVER=...; Trusted_Connection=...; DATABASE=...' SERVER=..."
db_connection = dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), .connection_string = connection_string)
my_table = tbl(db_connection, from = my_table_name)

# attempted query
tmp = my_table %>%
    mutate(new_col = case_when(col1 == col2 ~ "a",
                               col1 != col2 ~ "b"))

# check SQL code for query
show_query(tmp)
```

The resulting SQL query is:

```
SELECT 
    col1, col2,
    CASE
       WHEN CONVERT(BIT, IIF(col1 = col2, 1.0, 0.0))) THEN ('a')
       WHEN CONVERT(BIT, IIF(col1 <> col2, 1.0, 0.0))) THEN ('b')
    END AS new_col
FROM my_database.my_table_name
```

Running this code throws an error

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'THEN'

However the `ifelse` query works as expected:

```
# attempted query
tmp = my_table %>%
    mutate(new_col = ifelse(col1 == col2, "a", "b"))

# check SQL code for query
show_query(tmp)
```

The resulting SQL query is:

```
SELECT 
    col1, col2,
    CASE
       WHEN (CONVERT(BIT, IIF(col1 = col2, 1.0, 0.0))) = TRUE) THEN ('a')
       WHEN (CONVERT(BIT, IIF(col1 = col2, 1.0, 0.0))) = FALSE) THEN ('b')
    END AS new_col
FROM my_database.my_table_name
```

Note that in both cases the SQL syntax have been produced using `show_query`. Using `translate_sql` to produce the SQL code consistently produced much cleaner SQL syntax, but this is not the syntax that gets run on the server.

Does anyone else get these SQL queries? Any suggestions as to what is wrong and how to fix this?

## Updated

Posted as an [issue on the tidyverse](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/3774) and was informed that a solution has already been developed for `case_when(..., TRUE ~ "b")` being translated to `ELSE 'b'` ([here](https://github.com/tidyverse/dbplyr/pull/142)).

However, as this does not address the syntax that is causing this exception. Question edited to focus on syntax that is the cause.

## Update 2

Posted as an [issue on dbplyr](https://github.com/tidyverse/dbplyr/issues/148). A response from Christophe Dervieux (cderv) identifies that the cause appears to be that SQL server needs a special translation for `case_when` like it has for `ifelse`.

In the mean time, users can use multiple `ifelse` or `if_else` statements.

Comment: I also tried using `ifelse` instead of `case_when` this gives: `CASE WHERE (CONVERT(BIT, IIF(col1 = col2, 1.0, 0.0))) = TRUE) THEN ('a')` which does work. So perhaps this is a bug?

Comment: There is an [ongoing PR](https://github.com/tidyverse/dbplyr/pull/142) that propose to replace the `WHEN(TRUE)` by a `ELSE` clause. That should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Update 2 above:

This appears to be an issue effecting `case_when` for SQL server.

The work-around at present is to use multiple `ifelse` or `if_else` statements:

```
data %>%
    mutate(new_col = ifelse(condition1, val1, NA)) %>%
    mutate(new_col = ifelse(is.na(new_col) & condition2, val2, new_col)) %>%
    mutate(new_col = ifelse(is.na(new_col) & condition3, val3, new_col))
    # etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it just that you have got your dplyr syntax slightly wrong?

Try this

```
# attempted query
tmp = my_table %>%
    mutate(new_col = case_when(col1 == col2 ~ "a",
                               col1 == 'TRUE' ~ "b"
              # alternatively  col1 == 1 ~ "b"
))
```

Comment: Sorry, the incorrect dplyr syntax was just a typo from my trying to think in both R and SQL at once (fixed above). The syntax you have proposed still produces the same SQL code that results in an error.

Comment: Hmm, that's weird because it seems to work on my db... could it be to do with yow booleans are stored in your tables? as in are they stores as text 'TRUE' or 1/0? another thing to try would be using `if` and `else` (not `ifelse`)

Comment: `ifelse` works correctly, but `case_when` does not. The difference is that the resulting SQL produced by `ifelse` contains ` = TRUE` on the end, while the SQL produced by `case_when` does not.

Comment: I have no control over how booleans are stored in the db. I am not even sure how I could check this.